# Reading defined amount of numbers w/o array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Often in my tasks I've got to read previously defined amount of numbers in line and of course I know how they are separated. For example, let's say it'd be two coordinates separated with space. Here is what I actually do to read this line:

```
line = gets.split(' ').map(&:to_i)
```

It's fine, but I either have to call `line[0] .. line[1]` or add two lines for `a = line[0] ...`

Is there any way to **read defined amount of numbers and assign them to variables, not an array**?

---

**EDIT/TL:DR**: In the other words: I'm looking for Ruby's `scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
x, y = gets.split(' ').map(&:to_i)

puts "x: #{x}"
puts "y: #{y}"
```

Comment: Perfectly! Simplicity of Ruby can be really impressing.

Comment: Suppose `gets` returns `s = "1 2 3\n"`. Then `x #=> 1` and `y #=> 2`, but nobody gets the `3`. Similarly, if `s = "1\n",  `x #=> 1` and `y #=> nil`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland good point, but in this case, he knows exactly how many  inputs he is taking from the user and how they are separated as he mentioned in the question. So, if he knows he will take only two inputs and save them in x and y, he will not give '1 2 3\n' as input, he will only give '1 2\n'.

Comment: Technically, this does not satisfy the OP's requirement, as both `gets.split(' ')` and `gets.split(' ').map(&:to_i)` return arrays. You assign values from the latter array to variables using parallel assignment. This applies to my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know how many values will be in the string you cannot assign each value to a local variable. That's because you cannot use parallel assignment (see my comment on @K's answer) and, since Ruby v1.9, you cannot define local variables dynamically (e.g, `eval("x=1")` doesn't work).

You can assign the values to instance variables dynamically, like so:

```
arr = gets.chomp.split(/\s+/)
```

or

```
arr = gets.split(/\s+/).map(&:to_i)
```

depending on your needs.

Suppose

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Then:

```
arr.each_with_index { |x,i| instance_variable_set("@my_var#{i}", x) }

instance_variable_get(:@my_var0) #=> 1 
instance_variable_get(:@my_var1) #=> 2 
instance_variable_get(:@my_var2) #=> 3 
instance_variable_get(:@my_var3) #=> 4
```

But why would you want to do this?

**Edit:**

You know that `gets` will return a string that contains two substrings representing integers, separated by one or more spaces, and you wish to assign those two integers to variables `x` and `y`.

I expect you don't mind if unnamed temporary arrays are created, you just don't want any named arrays, such as:

```
arr = gets.map(&:to_i)
x,y = arr
```

If, however, you want to do this without creating any arrays, this might work:

```
s = gets                   #=> "1  -2\n"
x = s[/(-?\d+)\s/,1].to_i  #=>  1
y = s[/\s(-?\d+)/,1].to_i  #=> -2
```

I say "might" because I don't know if Ruby is creating any arrays in the background for her own use.

Alternatively, you could use positive lookarounds and no capture groups:

```
x = s[/-?\d+(?=\s)/].to_i  #=>  1
y = s[/(?<=\s)-?\d+/].to_i #=> -2
```

Comment: @K's answer and post is correct, since I know how many values I should except and how are they separated. I do exactly know a specification of input. But still thanks for your words!